# How to install Trimmomatic on Mac via terminal?

Tags: terminal

I used this code below to install Trimmomatic:

java -jar  SE[-threads ][-phred33|-phred64][-trimlog ]    ...

I got a syntax error saying: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

I appreciate it your help!

Comment: Which script are you running? if its java command that you are running then what's the exact command you are running?

Comment: I have the Trimmomatic jar file in /home/anacoda/jar but I don't know to install it. I was using this site(http://www.usadellab.org/cms/?page=trimmomatic) to run it via terminal and got a syntax error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Comment: Did you see example `java -jar trimmomatic-0.30.jar SE --phred33 input.fq.gz output.fq.gz ILLUMINACLIP:TruSeq3-SE:2:30:10 LEADING:3 TRAILING:3 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:15 MINLEN:36`?